# some elementary sources about distributive lattices, modular lattices, planar lattices, Hibi rings and Grobner basis

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, commutative-algebra

I read the following article "Finite lattices and Grobner bases" by T. Hibi and J. Herzog.  I can't attach the link because it can't be found online.

Many properties from article are proved in

J. Herzog and T. Hibi, Monomial Ideals, GTM Vol. 260 (Springer–Verlag, 2010). [3] T. Hibi, Distributive lattices, affine semigroup rings and algebras with straightening laws, in: Commutative Algebra and Combinatorics, edited by M. Nagata and H. Matsumura, Advanced Studies in Pure Math. Vol. 11 (North–Holland, Amsterdam, 1987), pp. 93–109.

Can I find this source online or some elementary sources about  distributive lattices, modular lattices, planar lattices, Hibi rings and Grobner bases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some information about distributive lattices and modular lattices in Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics*, which can be found online.

I found about this article on arxiv https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2445.pdf which contains information about Hibi rings and Groebner bases.

If you want to find more about Groebner bases, I recommend the book: D. Cox, J. Little, D. O'Shea - *Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms*.

Those sources mentioned in the article are very good resources. Too bad you can't find them. Also, it may be useful V. Ene and J. Herzog - *Groebner Bases in Commutative Algebra*, if you can find it.

Hope these resources are useful!